# How to detect strings with nan value in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to open a text document as follows.

```
input_data = pd.read_csv('input.tsv', header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3 )
L= input_data["title"] + '. ' + input_data["description"]
```

I found that some of my text equals to `nan`. Therefore, I tried the following approach.

```
import math
for text in L:

    if not math.isnan(text):
        print(text)
```

However, this returned me the following error `TypeError: must be real number, not str`

Is there a way to identify string `nan` values in python?

My `tsv`looks as follows

```
id  title   description major   minor
27743058    Partial or total open meniscectomy? : A prospective, randomized study.  In order to compare partial with total meniscectomy a prospective clinical study of 200 patients was carried out. At arthrotomy 100 patients were allocated to each type of operation. The two groups did not differ in duration of symptoms, age distribution, or sex ratio. The operations were performed as conventional arthrotomies. One hundred and ninety two of the patients were seen at follow up 2 and 12 months after operation. There was no difference in the period off work between the two groups. One year after operation, 6 of the 98 patients treated with partial meniscectomy had undergone further operation. In all posterior tears were found at both procedures. Among the 94 patients undergoing total meniscectomy, 4 required further operation. In each, part of the posterior horn had been left at the primary procedure. One year after operation significantly more patients who had undergone partial meniscectomy had been relieved of symptoms. However, the two groups did not show any difference in the degree of radiological changes present.    ### ###
27743057        Synovial oedema is a frequent complication in arthroscopic procedures performed with normal saline as the irrigating fluid. The authors have studied the effect of saline solution, Ringer lactate, 5% Dextran and 10% Dextran in normal saline on 12 specimens of human synovial membrane. They found that 10% Dextran in normal saline decreases the water content of the synovium without causing damage, and recommend this solution for procedures lasting longer than 30 minutes. ### ###
```

Comment: post a testable input fragment

Comment: Please read [ask] and then provide a [MCVE]. Your question is not answerable, we cannot investigate the error with the code you posted.

Comment: You probably also need to read [how to work with missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) in the `pandas` docs.

Comment: Updated the question with data

Comment: Since it is just a string you can simply compare like ```if text != "nan"```

Comment: @accdias I tried it but it did not work as 'nan' is float value

Comment: What about ```if not math.isnan(float(text))```?

Comment: @accdias I got this ValueError: could not convert string to float

Comment: Should not ```L``` be composed of ```data_input['major']``` and ```data_input['minor']``` instead? Why check for ```NaN``` on the ```title``` and ```description``` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that `math.isnan()` does not accept string values as input. You can try and see `math.isnan('any string')`.

Because you are in the pandas dataframe already, you are better off to use Pandas to handle your case. For example:

```
df.dropna()           # column-wise nan drop
df.dropna(axis=1)     # row-wise nan drop
```

Note that there are very useful arguments for additional convenience in dropna(), so do check those out from the doctring or corresponding manual entries.

As a word of advice for along the journey, when you work with pandas, it's good to keep in mind that often whatever you want to do, is easier to do just within native pandas functionality. Because Pandas is kind of a gold standard for this type of work, generally speaking whatever you are thinking you want to do (if it makes sense) the Pandas community had already thought of (and implemented) it.

Answer (score 1):

Your given dataframe is tough to replicate. Here is a sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["11","1", np.nan], [np.nan,"1", "2"], ['abc','def','ijk']],
             columns=["ix","a", "b"])
>>df

    a   b   c
0   11  1   NaN
1   NaN 1   2
2   abc def ijk
```

from the docs :  [df.dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```
df.dropna()
```

This returns all the rows which doesnot have any `nan` in any columns. 
Output:

```
    a   b   c
2   abc def ijk
```

for filtering columns which doesnot have any `nan`:

```
df.dropna(axis=1)

    b
0   1
1   1
2   def
```

For finding rows with `nan`:

```
df_nan= df.drop(list(df.dropna().index))
```

Also please check the `how=` builtin function which allows you to drop na values for `any` or `all` rows/columns depending on the axis selected.